pandoc and LaTeX: importing equation labels
Premise:
I know the pandoc-eqnos filter exists, but since it doesn't work (it also seems like a semi-abandoned project), I have no choice but to use this method.
Having said that, the objective of this filter is to extract the equation environments, create a standalone file containing only the equation and, above all, the related label, and to import the image thus created into the resulting .docx file.
All MWE stuffs:
.tex file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{pifont}
\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

\begin{equation}
    \underset{\mathrm{Einstein}}{E} = mc^2
\end{equation}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Etiam lobortis 
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.
Ut porttitor.
Praesent in sapien.
Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.
Sed interdum libero ut metus.
Pellentesque placerat.
Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris.
Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

\end{document}

Lua filter:
local file = "C:/Logs/test.tex"

function all_trim(s)
    return s:match("^%s*(.-)%s*$")
end

function file_exists(name)
    local f = io.open(name, "r")
    if f ~= nil then
        io.close(f)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

function get_line(filename, line_number)
    local i = 0
    for line in io.lines(filename) do
        i = i + 1
        if i == line_number then
            return line
        end
    end
    return nil -- line not found
end

function lines_from(file)
    if not file_exists(file) then
        return {}
    end
    local lines = {}
    for line in io.lines(file) do
        lines[#lines + 1] = line
    end
    return lines
end

-- tests the functions above

local lines = lines_from(file)

local section,equation = 0, 0


for k, v in pairs(lines) do
    if string.find(v, "\\section") then
        figure = 0
        section = section + 1
    end
    if string.find(v, "\\begin{equation}") then
        equation = equation + 1
    end
end


function Math(el)
    if (el.mathtype == "DisplayMath") then
        counter = counter + 1
        io.output("C:/Logs/output.tex")
        io.write("\\documentclass[preview]{standalone}", "\n")
        local i = 2
        for k, v in pairs(lines) do
            while not string.find(lines[i], "\\begin{document}") do
                io.write(lines[i], "\n") -- write preamble
                i = i + 1
            end
        end
        io.write("\\begin{document}", "\n")
        io.write("\\begin{equation}", "\n")
        io.write(el.text, "\n")
        io.write("\\label{"..section.."."..equation.."}", "\n")
        io.write("\\end{equation}", "\n")
        io.write("\\end{document}", "\n")
        io.close()
        os.execute("cd C:/Logs & pdflatex output.tex & convert -density 288 output.pdf -alpha off output.png")
        return { pandoc.Para({pandoc.Image({},"C:/Logs/output.png")})}
    end
end

The command line:
pandoc --from latex+raw_tex --filter pandoc-eqnos --lua-filter=filter.lua -s test.tex -o test.docx

And the relative error message:
Error running filter filter.lua:
Inline, list of Inlines, or string expected, got table


Solution: return pandoc.Inlines { pandoc.Image({},"C:/Logs/output.png") }
function Math(el)
    if (el.mathtype == "DisplayMath") then
        counter = counter + 1
        io.output("C:/Logs/output.tex")
        io.write("\\documentclass[preview]{standalone}", "\n")
        local i = 2
        for k, v in pairs(lines) do
            while not string.find(lines[i], "\\begin{document}") do
                io.write(lines[i], "\n") -- write preamble
                i = i + 1
            end
        end
        io.write("\\begin{document}", "\n")
        io.write("\\begin{equation}", "\n")
        io.write(el.text, "\n")
        io.write("\\label{"..section.."."..equation.."}", "\n")
        io.write("\\end{equation}", "\n")
        io.write("\\end{document}", "\n")
        io.close()
        os.execute("cd C:/Logs & pdflatex output.tex & convert -density 576 output.pdf -alpha off output.png")
        return pandoc.Inlines { pandoc.Image({},"C:/Logs/output.png") }
        --)
    end
end

